# Dynamical row links for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how to make the row numbers dynamic in my VBA code? For example, Row62 would always reference that particular line item even if a row was inserted above it and is now technically Row63.

The code is currently as follows:

```
Sub HistoricalMacro()
    Dim c As Long    
    c = Selection.Column

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False     

    'Format cells
    Cells(62, c).NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "" - ""_)"    
    Cells(72, c).NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "" - ""_)"    
    Cells(78, c).NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "" - ""_)"    
    Cells(79, c).NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "" - ""_)"   
     
    'Link cells Expense Summary sheet    
    Cells(55, c).FormulaR1C1 = "='Expense Summary'!R[-1]C"    
    Cells(59, c).Resize(5).FormulaR1C1 = "='Expense Summary'!R[-3]C"    
    Cells(68, c).Resize(5).FormulaR1C1 = "='Expense Summary'!R[-6]C"    
    Cells(76, c).Resize(4).FormulaR1C1 = "='Expense Summary'!R[-9]C"    
     
    'Update expense sum formula    
    Cells(64, c).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-5]C:R[-1]C)"    
    Cells(73, c).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-5]C:R[-1]C)"    
    Cells(80, c).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-4]C:R[-1]C)"
         
    'Clear grey tint in cell    
    Cells(55, c).Resize(25).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone         

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: how could a row be added between the time this macro begins and ends?

Comment: I mean a row was added to the worksheet so the row references were then off by 1 when the macro is run. Is there a way to update the Macro so that the row reference will not be impacted should this happen again?

Comment: Use [named ranges](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) for example. Give that row a name `MyRow` than you can then use like `Range("MyRow").Cells(1, c)`. Another option is to search for some unique identifier in that row. Eg the row contains a specific text that only occurs in that row, you can search for it and use that to get the row number. Actually the question is too broad to give a more detailed answer.